# Is there an existing algorithm in checking password strength? Or re-invent the wheel?

Tags: passwords, password-policy, password-checker

I've been thinking to develop an Android application which will tell the password strength of user-entered password.

In terms of checking password strength, I developed these *2 Algorithms* to check it. But I'm having second thought using these *Algorithms* because I don't think it's efficient.
What do you guys think?

**Here is my 2 Algorithms:**

### Average Method

```
Sample input = Password12@

1. Count the lowercase, uppercase, digits and special characters in the given String.
   Eg.
   Lowercase count = 7;
   Uppercase count = 1;
   Digits count = 2;
   SpecialCharacter count = 1;

2. Get the character count and multiply it to the size of given String.
   Eg.
    (Count * Size)
    (7 * 10) = 70
    (1 * 10) = 10
    (2 * 10) = 20
    (1 * 10) = 10

3. Add the following results
   Eg.
    70 + 10 + 20 + 10 = 110

4. Get the results which is the password strength.
   Eg.
    The password is 110% strong.
```

### Points Method

```
Sample input = Password12@

1. Set the points such that for every:
    Lowercase = 1 point given
    Uppercase = 5 points given
    Digits = 10 points given
    Special Character = 15 points given

2. Count the lowercase, uppercase, digits and special characters in the given String.
   Eg.
   Lowercase count = 7;
   Uppercase count = 1;
   Digits count = 2;
   SpecialCharacter count = 1;

3. Get the character count and add it to the given point and multiply the size of the given String.
   Eg.
    (Count + Point) * size
    (7 + 1) * 10 = 80;
    (1 + 5) * 10 = 60;
    (2 + 10) * 10 = 120;
    (1 + 15) * 10 = 160;

4. Add the following results and divide it to the size of given String and divide it by 4.
   Eg.
    //4 because count={uppercase, lowercase, digits, special character}
    80 + 60 + 120 + 160 = 420
    420 / 4 = 105

5. Get the result which is the pswword strength.
   Eg.
   The password strength is 105%.
```

My questions are:

- Which algorithm showed that has a better implementation?
- If the 2 given algorithms is inefficient, is there an existing algorithm that I can use to check the strength of the given password. Not like this, re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

A link to open source password strength checker:

https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

I didn't use it, just found it on google, check it out.

Your algorithms don't seem to get the job done well.

First one can be expressed as number of characters n^2, the kinds of character don't make a difference.

Second one is similar, it still doens't mean what kind of characters you input as the points only constitute a constant term in the equation:
(d + 10) * 10 = d * 10 + 100 (for digits). It isn't better, it just shows a larger score.

Both algorithm produce a number that is roughly a square of the length of the password, while the time to break it (or strength) depends more on the exponent of length.

Check this article from coding horror: http://blog.codinghorror.com/your-password-is-too-damn-short/

Time to break a random password (from the article):

> - 9 characters    2 minutes
> - 10 characters   2 hours
> - 11 characters   6 days
> - 12 characters   1 year
> - 13 characters   64 years
>
> The random.org generator is "only" uppercase, lowercase, and number

Answer (score 2):

Both of your algorithms have some inherent issues when checking password strengths:

The first algorithm basically just counts the length of the password and multiply with 10. Using this algorithm the password "passwordpassword" would get a rating of 160%. Way too strong for such a simple password.

The second algorithm is a bit more complex and uses weights, based on the type of character. However using this algorithm, the password "1234" would get a rating of a 100%. I am sure this is not what you want.

A general rule of thumb is to test a password strength based on a list of rules, and then weight those rules (together with the number of rules actually enforced by the password):

- Password must be atleast 8 characters long (10 pts)
- Password must contain atleast a lowercase letter (5 pts)
- Password must contain atleast an uppercase letter (5 pts)
- Password must contain atleast a digit (5 pts)
- Password must contain atleast a symbol (10 pts)
- Password must contain atleast 5 unique characters (5 pts)

You could then add the rules enforced together and multiply that number with the number of rules enforced multiplied by a weight. E.g:

"1234" = (5) + 1*10 = 15

"password" = (5+5) + 2*10 = 30

"password1" = (5+5+5) + 3*10 = 45

"password1234" = (5+5+5+10) + 4*10 = 65

"Password1234" = (5+5+5+5+10) + 5*10 = 80

"Passw@rd1234" = (5+5+5+5+10+10) + 6*10 = 100

This is just a simple formulation of how the rule based approach work. Personally I would weight the number of rules used exponentionally instead, and have a wide variety of rules. Basically, the more rules satisfied, the more complex the password, the more secure it is.

Comment: Where did you get the number 10 sir?

Comment: @camelCase Its just a random number based on the other values I used. It is just used to illustrate the approach. If you used e.g. 50 or 100 instead of 10 in my example then the value given for each individual rule would be too low and non essential. It needs to be balanced. Higher individual-rule values should of course reflect a higher "total rules used" weight.

Comment: I knew it! Thanks @Dryborg Nice explanation you got there

Comment: I wanted to thank you for posting this.  It seems much better than any other algorithm that I have been able to dream up.  I especially like the rating weights for the rules.